# IsolatedStorageSettings in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, isolatedstorage

I am converting a Silverlight application into a WPF application.

In my silverlight application I have this

```
    private static IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    public static String Division
    {
        get
        {
            if (userSettings.PropertyValues["DIVISION"] != null)
            {
                return (String)userSettings["DIVISION"];
            }
            else
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (userSettings.PropertyValues["DIVISION"] != null)
            {
                userSettings["DIVISION"] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                userSettings.DIVISON = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

but when copying this class to my WPF project I get the error

> The type or namespace 'IsolatedStorageSettings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

I have got the using statement

```
 using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
```

at the top of my class but still no luck. If this class simply does not exist in WPF is there an alternative?

Comment: Please see the [Using IsolatedStorageFile to store data in WPF Application class events](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/955/using-isolatedstoragefile-to-store-data-in-wpf-application-class-event) page on dotnetfunda.com.